# iOS7 and iPhone5 Splash screen issue

Tags: iphone, cordova, splash-screen

in my phonegap iPhone app,i replace Default-568h@2x~iphone image with my project image with same name, when i run on iPhone5 with iOS7 version its taking Default@2x~iphone.png image but not the Default-568h@2x~iphone, please help

Comment: Do you make Product - Clean?

Comment: Just make a clean and retry